# Redirect any index pages within any folder to another file, but still be able to include it

Tags: php

I need to redirect the following paths to `accessPoint.php`, but within `accessPoint.php` I will need to include/require the redirected file which was requested, can this be done?

`.htaccess` is within the root `./forms/.htaccess`.

- ./forms/form1/index.php
- ./forms/form2/index.php
- ./forms/form3/index.php
- ./forms/form4/index.php
- ./forms/form5/index.php

The above will redirect to 
- ./accessPoint.php

What I have now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /*/index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /accessPoint.php [R=302,L]
```

Current `accessPoint.php`, just testing by attempting to include one of the files, however nothing gets displayed:

```
<?php

    echo 'access point';

    include './forms/form1/index.php';
```

## Edit

Turns out what I have is working, however the files within the included file are now looking within the wrong folder, is there a solution to this?

For example the following:

```
<link href="css/structure.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is looking within: `http://web-forms.localhost/css/form.css`

When it should be looking within: `http://web-forms.localhost/forms/form1/css/form.css`

Comment: And what happens instead? Including a file does not use `.htaccess` after all

Comment: The file doesn't appear to get included, but I didn't know including a file doesn't use the `.htaccess` so this helps with my issue, thanks!

Comment: @NicoHaase See updated post

Comment: Please don't edit your question such that it contains a completely different one afterwards. Instead, open a new question for that - including all relevant information. In the current case, it could be interesting to see which URL you are using to load the page that does not load it's CSS, and then change the generation of that stylesheet link afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is correct. When you include a php file as you show, it doesn't go through the web server but rather just reads the local file system. I suspect your `RewriteCond` is incorrect.  Try this, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "\/index\.php$"
```

**EDIT:** To the update in the question. The way to fully deal with the situation is to use absolute paths, for example

```
<link href="/css/structure.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or, better yet, use php to determine what to include:

```
<?php
$BASE_PATH = '/';
echo "<link href=\"{$BASE_PATH}css/structure.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
?>
```

?>